# Can't connect to selenium grid on VM?

Tags: networking

I have a VM on the same network as my computer. I can remote into the VM and open up the selenium grid console (http://(ip):4444/grid/console) and it appears to be working fine.

When I try to open that same address from my own machine or any other machine on the network, I can't see it (I get a "webpage is unavailable"). I turned off all firewalls on my machine and the VM, and it didn't do anything.

Anyone run into this problem? Any suggestions?